# AND, OR , XOR a string with 127

Tags: c

The program should AND OR and XOR each character in a string with 127 and display the result.

My code works for AND,however it is displaying garbage value for XOR.

```
void main(){
    char str[]="Hello World";
    int i,len;
    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            printf("%c",str[i]&127);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            printf("%c",str[i]^127);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            printf("%c",str[i]|127);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


expected result:Hello World
                Hello World
                Hello World
```

Comment: What is the output you are actually getting?

Comment: I'm not sure by what reasoning your expected result would be `"Hello World"` three times.

Comment: XOR with `0b01111111` will produce garbage for printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Assuming plain 7-bit [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), doing a bitwise AND with `127` will not do anything. Bitwise OR will produce just `127` (which is the "delete" character). And XOR will give pretty odd results for most characters I guess. I suggest you do the calculation on paper, and check the results against an [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) table to see what you get.

Answer (score 7):

It is expected to see "garbage" with OR or XOR.

Your string `Hello World` is pure ASCII, so it consists of characters with encoding values less than `127`.

A bitwise AND with `127` does not change the value, so you will see `Hello World`.

A bitwise OR with `127` will set all values to `127` in your case. For characters from other languages you may get values above `127`.

A bitwise XOR with `127` will invert the 7 low bits of every character resulting in other characters which may be printable characters or not.

That means when you print the characters you will see "garbage".

To understand the result of the bitwise logical operation you could do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        int original, modified;
        original = str[i];
        modified = str[i]^127;
        printf("i %d char %c orig %02x mod %02x\n", i, original, original, modified);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        #include <string.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char str[]="Hello World";
char str1[11],str2[11],str3[11];
int i,len;
len = strlen(str);
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    str1[i] = str[i]&127;
    printf("%c",str1[i]);
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    str2[i] = str[i]^127;
        printf("%c",str2[i]^127);
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    str3[i] = str[i]|127;
    printf("%c",str3[i]&str1[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This program will print 'Hello World' by applying & (bitwise and), | (bitwise or) and ^ (bitwise XOR).